# How to append li inside new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a HTML markup like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

How can I convert above HTML into this:

```
<div class="main"><ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li></ul></div>

<div class="main"><ul><li>Item 3</li><li>Item 4</li></ul></div>

<div class="main"><ul><li>Item 5</li><li>Item 6</li></ul></div>

<div class="main"><ul><li>Item 7</li><li>Item 8</li></ul></div>
```

Comment: First off, what have you tried, then we'll know whether you're looking for vanilla js, jquery, mootools, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$('ul > li:nth-child(2n-1)').each(function() {
    $(this).next().add(this).wrapAll('<div class="main"><ul></ul></div>');
}).eq(0).closest('div').unwrap();
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B9bA7/)**</kbd>